# How to load non-entity queries?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, wcf-ria-services

I have this in my WCF domain service:

```
    public List<string> GetTop5ActiveUsersByManagementMessages()
    {
        return this.ObjectContext.Logs
        .Where(w => w.Message == "Created User" || 
               w.Message == "Removed User" || w.Message == "Updated User")
        .GroupBy(w => w.Username)
        .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
        .Select(s => s.Key)
        .Take(5).ToList();
    }
```

Now I want to load it in my view model like this:

```
context.Load(context.GetTop5ActiveUsersByManagementMessages(), 
             GetActiveUsersCallback, true);
```

However, it complains about needing to specify the types explicitly.  How do I fix this?

Comment: What type of object is context, a DataContext?

Comment: @Amasuriel DomainContext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Non-entity queries' aren't actually a thing. What you've written is an 'Invoke' operation. You just need to call it differently from the client.

```
context.GetTop5ActiveUsersByManagementMessages(GetActiveUsersCallback, null)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you add a method to the DataContext, it expects you to specify certain things like the return type in the configuration for that context.

These articles talk about exposing stored procedures as methods, but it will give you an idea what EF is expecting.

If you do create a new method via the designer, you can probably then go into the EF XML files and add return type definitions etc by hand if you want to.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384566.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629304.aspx.

I think you need to "wire up" the method with EF configuration or it won't play nice with you.